# Inheriting from a tuple subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, tuples

I'm using a third-party module which provides classes that inherit from `tuple`. However, I'd like to add some functionality to these classes, so I have sub-classed. The resultant inheritance hierarchy looks like:

`MyClass` -> `LibClass` -> `tuple`

Is there any reason inheritance from a `tuple` sub-class should be *expected* to fail?

### The gory details

Everything seems to be peachy at first. However, utilising a slice (`instance[:6]`) to access a range of values from an instance of `MyClass` results in an error like:

`SystemError: <method-wrapper '__getitem__' of LibClass object at 0x1010101010> returned NULL without setting an error`

Doing the exact same thing with an instance of `LibClass` works flawlessly.

To further add to the mystery, regular indexed access (`instance[5]`) on an instance of `MyClass` works flawlessly.

Obviously `tuple` inheritance isn't *exactly* like regular class inheritance (i.e. `__new__` must be overridden rather than `__init__`). However, to my knowledge `LibClass` is doing so correctly e.g.

```
def __new__(cls, *members):
    mat = [x * 1.0 for x in members] + [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    return tuple.__new__(cls, mat)
```

I don't believe implementing `__new__` in `MyClass` is necessary given the implementation in `LibClass` correctly passes through `cls` (admittedly I had to fork the library to achieve that). Nonetheless, for posterity I did also try implementing `__new__` directly in `MyClass` (just copied and pasted the `LibClass` implementation).

I should also note that I'm not doing anything wacky in `MyClass`. In fact if I do *nothing at all* the problem still persists e.g.

```
class MyClass(lib.LibClass):
    pass
```

Another thing worth noting, `LibClass` does not have a custom `__getitem__` implementation - it's simply inheriting that behaviour from `tuple`.

*Python 3.6.1*

### The extra gory (real) details

`LibClass` is in fact `Affine` from `planar`, my fork can be found here:

https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/planar/blob/master/lib/planar/transform.py

### Reproduction

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/planar#egg=planar
python

>>> import planar
>>> class Affine(planar.Affine):
...     pass
... 
>>> planar.Affine.identity()[:6]
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
>>> Affine.identity()[:6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: <method-wrapper '__getitem__' of Affine object at 0x10e2b9ba8> returned NULL without setting an error
```

It was pointed out in the comments that in the above reproduction `identity()` returns a constant. So it *really* shouldn't be failing. I can't explain that. However, I should probably add that it was a pretty poor reproduction by me. My real world usage is closer to:

```
>>> Affine.translation((0, 0))[:6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: <method-wrapper '__getitem__' of Affine object at 0x10f8d5ee8> returned NULL without setting an error
>>> planar.Affine.translation((0, 0))[:6]
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

which also fails in the same fashion.

Mind you, the failure with the constant really has me scratching my head.

### Something `planar` specific

Trying different Python versions, it fails similarly:

#### 3.3.6

```
Python 3.3.6 (default, Apr 12 2017, 17:20:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import planar
>>> class Affine(planar.Affine):
...     pass
... 
>>> planar.Affine.identity()[:6]
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
>>> Affine.identity()[:6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

#### 2.7.11

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, May  2 2016, 14:38:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import planar       
>>> class Affine(planar.Affine):
...     pass
... 
>>> planar.Affine.identity()[:6]
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
>>> Affine.identity()[:6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

However, I was **not able to reproduce** the problem when reduced to its simplest form i.e. (Python 2.7.11):

```
>>> class LibClass(tuple):
...     def __new__(cls, *members):
...         return tuple.__new__(cls, *members)
... 
>>> class MyClass(LibClass):
...     pass
... 
>>> LibClass((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))[:3]
(1, 2, 3)
>>> MyClass((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))[:3]
(1, 2, 3)
```

I also tried moving the definition of `LibClass` to a separate `lib.py` to ensure the error wasn't somehow related to Python modules, but it worked as above.

So the issue is something specific to `planar` and/or its `Affine` class. It'd be nice to know exactly what is causing the problem though.

Comment: This should not be expected to fail. Is their subclass written in C? Can you tell us what the real `LibClass` is, and/or provide a source code link so we can take a look?

Comment: "admittedly I had to fork the library to achieve that" - can you link to your fork?

Comment: @user2357112 I've updated the question with the link to the real code at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: My best guess is that either some C extension module you're using screwed things up somehow, or you're running into a CPython bug related to tuples and/or slices. Maybe try it on Python 3.5, or on a different computer.

Comment: Hey, `identity()` returns the same object whether you're calling it on `planar.Affine` or the subclass. That's the *same* object that's failing to slice the second time.

Comment: @user2357112 Wow! Quite right. I've updated the question, but I think the issue with the constant just further dilutes the underlying cause! May well be a python bug after all.

Comment: Ah, found it. There is indeed a C extension module involved - `planar` isn't using your edited `planar.transform` module at all. It's using `planar.c`, a C version. I'm looking through that for the bug now.

Comment: @user2357112 Wow! You're a saint. Thanks for the dedication!

Comment: @user2357112 By the way, feel free to post your comment above as the answer and I'll happily accept (although I'll be busy for a few hours). You've been more than helpful, I don't expect you to fix the C implementation of some random module! I'm more familiar with C than I am Python, so I can dig around and/or remove the native implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is indeed a buggy extension module involved. `planar` isn't using your edited `planar.transform` module at all; it's using `planar.c`, a C implementation of `planar`'s functionality with its own `Affine` class.

At least part of the problem seems to be due to a bug in [`Affine_getitem`](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/planar/blob/master/lib/planar/ctransform.c#L678):

```
static PyObject *
Affine_getitem(PlanarAffineObject *self, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    double m;

    assert(PlanarAffine_Check(self));
    if (i < 6) {
        m = self->m[i];
    } else if (i < 8) {
        m = 0.0;
    } else if (i == 8) {
        m = 1.0;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(m);
}
```

where it returns `NULL` without setting an `IndexError` for an out-of-range index.

`planar` is no longer maintained, so a bug report won't be handled. There may be better modules to use.